# Where to find my git clone repos on my mac?

Tags: python, github

I git cloned files on my Mac, now I want to delete them, but can't find, where is the location of default store?

Answer (score 2):

The clone happens in the directory from where you issued the command if not specified explicitly. If you have lost the terminal, then search for all the folders with a `.git` directory and you will locate it.